# Include text-style citation call-out at the start of formatted bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have the bib file `mybib.bib`

```
@article{art1,
author = {Foster, Joe and Burton, Nathan and Cook, Andrew},
journal = {Journal 1},
pages = {1-10},
title = {{Title 1}},
volume = {1},
year = {2018}
}
```

Using `\citet{art1}` I get *Foster et al. (2018)*, as desired. I would like the formatted reference in the bibliography to start with *(Foster et al. (2018))*, i.e.,

> (Foster et al. (2018)) Joe Foster, Nathan Burton, and Andrew Cook. Title 1. Journal 1, 1:1-10, 2018.

I have tried using the `natbib` package in combination with `apalike` (starts with all authors, not the abbreviated version with et al. as in the in-text citation call-out) and `plainnat` (gives the desired format, but is lacking the first part).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\begin{document}    
Citation 1: \citet{art1}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why would you wish to clutter up the bibliography in this manner? If your readers really need this type of help, i.e., if they can't be trusted to figure out on their own how to associate a citation call-out of the form `Foster et al. (2018)` with an entry that starts with `Joe Foster, Nathan Burton, and Andrew Cook....`, they must be in deep, deep trouble...

Comment: @Mico It is indeed intended to make it easier to find the right reference in the bibliography. Especially for references with the same (first) author(s) and same year. e.g, Foster et al. (2018a) and because the bibliography includes the first names, so it starts with Joe rather than Foster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that achieving your formatting objective with BibTeX and `natbib` will require a major hack of whichever bibliography style file is in use. It's probably easier to achieve your formatting objective with `biblatex`; I'm not a `biblatex` expert, I'm afraid, but maybe somebody else can offer some `biblatex` help.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your query a bit, to help readers spot the objective more rapidly. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: Replacing `natbib` with `biblatex` would be an option for me, but I do not know how to solve it `biblatex` either